# Why is there no variable template template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates, variable-templates

I'm planning to create a variable template that takes (variable) template-template parameter and one typename:

```cpp
template <template <typename> auto MetaPredicate, typename T>
constexpr bool has_predicate_v_ = requires {
  { MetaPredicate<T> } -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
}
```

Where the expectations are:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct dummy_01 {
    inline static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool dummy_01_v = dummy_01<T>::value;

std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_predicate_v_<dummy_01_v, int> << '\n'; // true
```

But that doesn't work. It would be useful if they exist in standard.

Another case is to create a metafunction `count_if`:

```cpp
template <typename Type, template <typename> bool Predicate>
struct count_if {
    inline static constexpr size_t value = /** ... **/;
};

template <typename Type, template <typename> bool Predicate>
inline constexpr size_t count_if_v = count_if<Type, Predicate>::value;

// ...
count_if_v<std::tuple<int, double, void, size_t, unsigned short>, 
           std::is_integral_v> // yields to 3
```

There is also a proposal relating to my question: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2008r0.html

- Why are there currently no variable template-template parameters/arguments?
- What is the status of the proposal?
- Are there any possible alternatives for variable template-template parameters/arguments?

Comment: The answer is most likely that no one has taken the time to write a proposal for this and gotten it approved by the standard comittee. An alternative is to use `dummy_01` as a template template parameter.

Comment: Also, the link is broken.

Comment: I've corrected the link because of a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already linked to the proposal, so you’ve largely answered the question yourself.  You might not know about the [paper tracker](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/745) that can answer the “status” question; it says that more motivating **examples** are sought (which might very well have been delayed by the pandemic), so maybe you should contribute yours!

As for alternatives, the usual one is to key on the **trait** rather than the helper variable template.  Obviously new code might have to wrap a (foundational) variable template with a helper trait class template to take advantage of this, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

To extend @DavisHerring's answer: I think there is little use of it: I don't really see the advantage of using the helper variable template instead of the **trait** directly. Here is e.g. what I would do for your two examples:

In **C++20** I would actually write a [**`concept`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints)

```
template <template <typename> class Predicate, typename T>
concept is_predicate = requires {
  std::same_as<decltype(Predicate<T>::value), bool>;
};
```

that makes sure that a given predicate has a static `bool` member variable `value`. Before that you might additionally use [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) instead or not use SFINAE at all.

**Example 1:**

```
template <template <typename> class MetaPredicate, typename T>
requires is_predicate<MetaPredicate, T>
constexpr bool has_predicate_v_ = requires {
  std::same_as<decltype(MetaPredicate<T>::value), bool>;
};
```

and then call it with the trait `has_predicate_v_<dummy_01, int>` instead of the alias.

[Try it here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rQvKjpycbzDcYTZd)

**Example 2:**

```
template <template <typename> class Predicate, typename... Ts>
requires (is_predicate<Predicate, Ts> && ...)
struct count_if {
  inline static constexpr size_t count = ((Predicate<Ts>::value == true ? 1 : 0) + ...);
};
```

and again call it with the trait [`std::is_integral`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) instead: `count_if<std::is_integral, int, double>::count`.

[Try it here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VmMS0eDR7AuIG9ID)